# Relatively normalizing values for collaborative filtering

Tags: algorithms, stata, normalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Relatively normalizing values for collaborative filtering](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21946/relatively-normalizing-values-for-collaborative-filtering)

I am trying to derive a formula for my collaborative algorithm problem to calculate popularity rating of an item.

I am considering three factors to calculate rating for an item based on three different ratings a, b and c, each with weight w1, w2 and w3. The cumulative rating is:

w1 × a + w2 × b + w3 × c
In this equation, I want to give b less weight than a, i.e. w1 > w2 > w3.

But the problem is that how should I decide/calculate the weights such that they maintain this relative ordering when normalized (I am not looking for linear normalization) i.e.

w1 × a > w2 × b > w3 × c
Is there a way to calculate w1, w2, w3 dynamically and what normalization process I should use or is recommended?

It would be really helpful to get comments on the approach as well.